# wx.Grid and wx.StockCursor

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I've created wx.Grid widget inside my frame and I want to change my type of cursor if the user is using the grid widget. I've managed to do that with `wx.StockCursor` and `.SetCursor methods` but my cursor keeps returning to standard cursor if the user moves the cursor above the intersections of cell and row borders. What is causing this?

```
import wx
import wx.grid as Gridw

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Data selection', size=(785, 540))
        self.Centre()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        self.grid = Gridw.Grid(panel)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(250, 250)
        self.grid.EnableDragGridSize(0)
        self.grid.DisableDragColSize()
        self.grid.DisableDragRowSize()
        self.grid.SetColMinimalWidth(0, 100)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_v.Add(wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Button'), 1, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(sizer_v, 0)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.Show(True)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        cross_c = wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS)
        self.grid.SetCursor(cross_c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is related to that you've disabled grid resizing via `EnableDragGridSize(0)`, `DisableDragColSize()` and `DisableDragRowSize()`. This can somewhat explain why you are seeing standard cursor on the cell borders.

Not sure if it'll help you since I don't know what OS are you using, but this works for me on linux:

```
cross_c = wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS)
self.grid.GetGridWindow().SetCursor(cross_c)
```

One more option is to listen for `EVT_MOTION` and set cursor in the event listener:

```
self.cross_c = wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS)
self.grid.GetTargetWindow().SetCursor(self.cross_c)
wx.EVT_MOTION(self.grid.GetGridWindow(), self.OnMouseMotion)

def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
    self.grid.GetTargetWindow().SetCursor(self.cross_c)
    evt.Skip()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It acts the same, at first the cursor is changed but as soon as I move it at the intersection of cell and row borders it switches back to normal cursor. :/

Comment: Second method works almost perfectly! Cursor keeps change to a standard one but as soon as I move the mouse of the intersections it switches back to cross type.